# quotient groups and SLOCC

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces

I have a math-physics question, which is based on an interest in SLOCC systems for black hole entanglement. The Cartan decomposition of a group $G$ such that $H = G/K$ is such that the derivation or Lie algebraic generators obey
$$
[\mathfrak h,~\mathfrak h]~\subset~ \mathfrak h,~[\mathfrak h,~\mathfrak k]~\subset~ \mathfrak k,~[\mathfrak k,~\mathfrak k]~\subset~ \mathfrak h
$$
Assume then that we have addition quotient structure with $B~=~G/A$ and $C~=~A/K$. It is then tempting to see relationships between $H~=~G/K$ and the two $B~=~G/A$ and $C~=~A/K$. In particular I am interested in the relationship
$$
G/K~\rightarrow~G/A\otimes A/K.
$$
The arrow can represent a relationship or for that matter a symmetry breaking process. I have worked out some parts of this, but as a physicist I need a bit of a sanity check on this, as this is a bit outside my area. The mathematical question is what is this relationship?

Comment: The quotients $G/K, G/A$ are manifolds, not groups (I assume that $A$ is a maximal split torus); I have no idea what $A/K$ is. In any case, tensor product of manifolds does not make much sense. Also, assuming that $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup and  $\mathfrak k$ is its Lie algebra, your commutation relations are wrong, you should interchange $\mathfrak k$ and $\mathfrak h$.

Answer (score 0):

I am a guest here, or just joined. I am responding to the comment by Studiosus. I am thinking of quotients such as $O(n+2)/O(n)$, then the tensor product, 
$$
\frac{O(n+2)}{O(n+1)}\otimes\frac{O(n+1)}{O(n)}~=~S^n\otimes S^{n-1}.
$$
This is then a Cartesian product of spheres. My observation is that this seems to be a sort of compactification on the manifold $O(n+2)/O(n)$

You are right about getting the $\mathfrak h$ and $\mathfrak k$ switched.

Comment: Then please correct the commutators in the question itself.  In view of your example, K is not a maximal compact subgroup, I suppose it is the fixed point set of some involution of G. Also, please explain what A is. I suspect that it is some closed connected subgroup of G such that K<A<G. Even in your example, there is no natural map of G/K to the product.

Comment: I actually have the commutators right. I wrote this up during lunch break so I rattled it off pretty quickly. I agree there is no map, but this is meant to be more in the way of a compactification, similar to Calabi-Yau compactification in Kaluza-Klein theory.